# How to VALIDATE Bind DropDownList in Asp.NET?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to validate 2 dropdown lists. The list items are generated at the runtime. Please help!

**aspx.vb code**

```
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            For index = 0 To 25
                a1.Items.Add(New ListItem(index.ToString(), index.ToString()))
                a2.Items.Add(New ListItem(index.ToString(), index.ToString()))

            Next
        End If
  End Sub
```

**aspx code**

```
<tr>
  <td class="auto-style3">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="a1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="auto-style3">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="a2" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What exactly are you validating? You filled the DropDownList. Are your entries not valid?

Comment: I want to add a required field validator and show error message on a label